# Возможно ли обтекание flex-элемента?

Tags: css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, flexbox

Подскажите можно ли заставить остальные элементы flex-контейнера обтекать определенный элемент?

[image: Макет]

Верстаю на flexbox'ах, все делаю одним списком `ul`, он же и является контейнером. Необходимо заставить все элементы списка содержащие маленькие изображения обтекать `li` в котором находится картинка **adidas**. Это вообще возможно используя flexbox? Знаю что можно на гридах, но гриды использовать нельзя. Да и еще нужно чтобы `li` с adidas была как бы приклеена к правому краю, то есть при изменении ширины окна элемент оставался всегда у правого края и за ним не выстраивались остальные элементы.

Сейчас картина такая

[image: Мой результат]

Answer (score 1):

Через `flex` никак.
Можно решить через `float`, если нельзя использовать `grid`:

```css
.parent {
  width: 302px;
  padding: 0;

}

.children {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 78px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;

  background: red;
  list-style-type: none;

}

.children--first {
  float: right;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<ul class='parent'>
  <li class='children children--first'>1</li>
  <li class='children'>2</li>
  <li class='children'>3</li>
  <li class='children'>4</li>
  <li class='children'>5</li>
  <li class='children'>6</li>
  <li class='children'>7</li>
  <li class='children'>8</li>
  <li class='children'>9</li>
  <li class='children'>10</li>
  <li class='children'>11</li>
  <li class='children'>12</li>
</ul>
```